# Problem loading .NET assembly by a CGI Module in IIS 8

Tags: .net, cgi, iis-8, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a CGI Module running in IIS8. I fails when trying to load .NET Assemblies.

The executable is a Progress (OpenEdge) Application from the 20th Century.

Looking with Fusion++, I get this log:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry (30/10/2020 @ 8:59:55) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable \\?\C:\MiaWeb\bin\nph-cybermia.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Progress.NetUI, Version=11.7.0.1811, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file://?/C:/MiaWeb/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = nph-cybermia.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/MiaWeb/bin/Progress.NetUI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/MiaWeb/bin/Progress.NetUI/Progress.NetUI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/MiaWeb/bin/Progress.NetUI.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/MiaWeb/bin/Progress.NetUI/Progress.NetUI.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

The file Progress.NetUI.DLL can be foundin C:\MiaWeb\bin .

Is there a way to get more information about what is going wrong?

```
C:\OpenEdge\1175_32\DLC\bin>sn -T Progress.NetUI.dll

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Progress.NetUI.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly
```

The URL file://?/C:/ seems odd. Other than that, maybe it has to do with IIS8 and CGI Module blocking .NET Assemblies? Maybe it should be strongly named?

Comment: Could you please share how you are loading assembly in iis? make sure your dll file is set to allow in the IIS ISAPI and CGI restriction. did you register the assembly in GAC? if you are loading the assembly from bin folder then open web.config in a text editor,Add this code to /configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly:`<assemblyIdentity name="Your.Assembly.Name" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<codebase version="1.0.0.0" href="/bin/Your.Assembly.Name.dll" />`

Comment: Actually it's a Progress process (Progress = OpenEdge = 'old' 4GL Language) that is loading the Assembly. Progress has support for .NET. So behind the scenes it's probably C/C++ loading Assemblies. How Progress solves/handles things is a black box for us. Tried the web.config, but no success.